# Rails Beginner - How to define 3 buttons enabling a user to make a choice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am aware this is a very basic question, we are very new to rails and have been unable to find a specific answer to this question.

Background: We have just 1 database containing product information (called Product), one column (type) contains information regarding the product type and is either a value of 1 or 2.

Aim: create 3 buttons on a page which correspond to different user choices
e.g. Button 1 - show items of type 1; Button 2 - show items of type 2; Button 3 - show all items.

Ideally the information regarding the button pressed should be visible to a number of pages within a class (we have an index page, as well as 3 others in the controller)

Would somebody be able to provide an outline of the code required to do this please?
I am guessing it is some combination involving the ..._controller.rb and..._helper.rb?

Thanks a lot for your patience

Comment: Is it possible to use JavaScript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I would do is the following.

First, create a scope or named_scope in your Project model for finding projects by type. You'll then be able to use this scope to query your projects depending on type.

```
# Rails 3
class Project
  scope :by_type, lambda{ |type| where(type: type.to_i) unless type.nil? }
end

#Rails 2
class Project
  named_scope :by_type, lambda do |type|
    { :conditions => { :type => type.to_i } } unless type.nil?
  end
end
```

Next, create a before filter in your controller to load the projects of that type. The before filter should be applied to all pages where you want the buttons to be present:

```
class ProjectsController
  before_filter :load_projects, :only => [:index, :action1, :action2]

  protected

  def load_projects
    @projects = Project.by_type(params[:type])
  end
end
```

Finally, create a partial for the buttons that you can include in the views that have the option of displaying different project types:

```
# _project_options.html.erb
<%= link_to "Button 1", :controller => params[:controller], :action => params[:action], :type => '1' %>
<%= link_to "Button 2", :controller => params[:controller], :action => params[:action], :type => '2' %>
<%= link_to "Button 3", :controller => params[:controller], :action => params[:action], :type => '' %>
```

You can then include this partial in each of your related views. And you'll be able to display the projects by doing something like this (if you have an _projects.html.erb partial defined):

```
render @projects
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it could be very close to being exactly what we were after.

Comment: Thanks for this, it could be very close to being exactly what we were after. The goal was to have an index page which summarises all the products in the database - before making the changes above, this page was working correctly and was displaying summary information (e.g. Unique brands from the brand column, unique colours, ...).  Once the above suggestion was added to the site, this summary information could not be calculated and a nil array was reported.  Is this because no button has been pressed yet? If so, is there a way to set a default of assuming Button 3 has been pressed?

Comment: Yes - I modified the controller code in my solution for this case. It basically involves removing the "if params.has_key?(:type)" in the before filter.

Comment: Sorry to keep pestering you - still not quite there, although probably due to something i have done.  Put your code in product.rb, productfinder_controller.rb (where our index file is) and index itself, respectively.  The buttons appear correctly, however, it crashes on - 
    <% @distinctbrands.each do |distinctbrand| %>
    <h4><%= distinctbrand %></h4>
    <% end %> where it says it is evaluating nil.each... This is defined in productfinder_controller as: def index
      @distinctbrands = @product.find( :all, :order => 'brand ASC', :select => 'brand' ).map{ |i| i.brand }.uniq   THANKS!

Comment: Only other thing I thought of that may be useful to know is that I have actually replaced the :type => '1' command to :type => 'some text' and similarly for '2'.

Comment: I think the issue is probably that you haven't defined @product. This seems to be un-related to the @products compilation though. You might want to try posting another question for that issue.

Comment: Glad I could help. Be sure to mark the question as answered :)

Answer (score 1):

You can load all the Products and then hide them selectively with some javascript. Just add a class to your markup for each type of product, like this:

```
<%= link_to @product.name, product_path(@product), :class => @product.type %>
```